# How can I insert an image into a Session variable in sql query?

Tags: php, sql, image, session

hello I'm trying to start a session in the sql login query
to save the image in a Session variable and display it. How can I insert an image into a Session variable in sql query?

Query:

```
    function checkuser($conexionBd,$us,$pass){

            $sentence= $conexionBd->prepare("SELECT us_id, us_img FROM users where us_us=? AND us_pass=?");
            $img='us_img';
            session_start();
        $sentence->execute(array($us, $pass));
            if ($sentence->rowCount()==1) {

            $_SESSION['img']= $img;

            header("Location:img.php");
            exit();
            }else{

            echo 'user or password incorrect';
            }

            }
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: You execute the query but never retrieve any results. Retrieve the results and you will have the `us_img` value from the database which you may store in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to load your image and convert it using base64.

```
$path = 'myfolder/myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Then you add $base64 variable to session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['product_number'.$base64 ] = true;
```